# Is there any difference between CassandraCSharpDriver and YugaByteCassandraCSharpDriver?

Tags: c#, yugabytedb

I found there is a YugaByteCassandraCSharpDriver on NuGet package manager while in yugabyte official site docs [showed](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/quick-start/build-apps/csharp/#ycql) using CassandraCSharpDriver.

which one should we use for C#?

what is the difference between YugaByteCassandraCSharpDriver and CassandraCSharpDriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [YugaByteCassandraCSharpDriver](https://github.com/yugabyte/cassandra-csharp-driver) because YugabyteDB partitioning policy is different from Cassandra. As a result, even though the drivers are API compatible (for the common functionality), there'll be a performance advantage in using the YugabyteDB driver because requests can be routed to the correct/optimal node in the common case.

The YugabyteDB driver also support extra features that aren't present in Cassandra (such as the JSONB datatype).

The docpage is old and will be updated.

Comment: And Are [these](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2014/06/4-simple-rules-when-using-datastax-drivers-cassandra) 4 rules true for  YugaByteCassandraCSharpDriver too?

Comment: @AliZeinali yes. All operations are atomic and transactional.

Comment: OK thanks. I have a lot of different question about this yugabyte :) .  where can i ask them?

Comment: I exactly was looking for JSONB feature in YB driver but i couldn't find it. Could you please give an example?

Comment: @AliZeinali see usage in tests https://github.com/yugabyte/cassandra-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra.YugaByte.Tests/JsonTest.cs

Comment: Does YugaByteCassandraCSharpDriver  support transactions?

Comment: @AliZeinali all DML are transactional when creating a table with `transactions = { 'enabled' : true }` https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/ddl_create_table/#table-properties-1

Comment: I mean can we BEGIN and END transactions with driver without writing CQL?

Comment: I think you mean multi query transactions like in YSQL ? Currently all transactions can only span 1 query (like autocommit in YSQL/Postgresql)

Comment: I'm not sure what is multi query transactions. I'm just looking for something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.begintransaction?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: That's not possible in YCQL (only in YSQL). You can't have client-controlled transactions. You have to put all your DML in 1 query string.